# Can I replace "If so" with "that being said"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Do you like eating? If so, how about cooking?

Can I replace it with this: Do you like eating? That being said, how about cooking?

> I don't expect to be, but if so, I'll let you know.

Can I replace it with this: I don't expect to be. That being said, I'll let you know.

Comment: You really need to provide more context. That said, your second example is probably better this way: I don't expect to be [elected, represented, told, levitated, etc. etc.] but if I am, I'll let you know.

Comment: @ Lambie I'm penitent. Those are just examples from a dictionary. The sentence you suggested is really helpful. Thanks a millon. Might I enquire of you sth further? What did you think of the former case? "Do you like eating? That being said, How about cooking?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't expect to be, but if so, I'll let you know.**

That example is probably better this way:

**I don't expect to be [elected, represented, told, levitated, etc. etc.] but if I am**, I'll let you know.

**Do you like eating? If so, how about cooking?** That sentence is fine. **If so** means: **If you do**.

As for **that being said**, it usually is used to set off a thought or thoughts after another one has been expressed. It would usually not follow a simple question. [Do you like eating? That being said, how about cooking?] In that sentence there is a question, which really doesn't lend itself to being followed by "that being said".

**I like eating, especially in expensive restaurants. Eating at home is alright if my father cooks because he is a chef. My mother really doesn't cook very well and even burns the food!. That being said, I would not turn down an invitation to a fast-food restaurant because I really don't know what they are like.**

Answer (score 2):

No, "if so" and "that being said" do not usually mean the same thing.

"If so" is a true conditional: "if [whatever has just been stated or asked about] is so".

"That being said" ignores the truth or not of what precedes; and doesn't really make sense following a question.